# Без особых причин перестал собираться проект

Tags: kotlin, build, dagger2, android-gradle

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity, androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder.SupportParentable>
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:316)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:329)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.java:268)
at dagger.shaded.auto.common.MoreTypes.nonObjectSuperclass(MoreTypes.java:899)
at dagger.internal.codegen.DaggerTypes.nonObjectSuperclass(DaggerTypes.java:67)
at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingFactory.getInjectionSites(BindingFactory.java:538)
at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingFactory.membersInjectionBinding(BindingFactory.java:494)
at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectBindingRegistryImpl.tryRegisterMembersInjectedType(InjectBindingRegistryImpl.java:274)
at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectBindingRegistryImpl.tryRegisterMembersInjectedType(InjectBindingRegistryImpl.java:255)
at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectProcessingStep$1.visitVariableAsField(InjectProcessingStep.java:52)
at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectProcessingStep$1.visitVariableAsField(InjectProcessingStep.java:42)
at javax.lang.model.util.ElementKindVisitor6.visitVariable(ElementKindVisitor6.java:229)
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol.accept(Symbol.java:1237)
at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectProcessingStep.process(InjectProcessingStep.java:74)
at dagger.internal.codegen.TypeCheckingProcessingStep.lambda$process$0(TypeCheckingProcessingStep.java:51)
at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.forEach(RegularImmutableMap.java:187)
at dagger.internal.codegen.TypeCheckingProcessingStep.process(TypeCheckingProcessingStep.java:48)
at dagger.internal.codegen.TypeCheckingProcessingStep.process(TypeCheckingProcessingStep.java:34)
at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:330)
at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:181)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:99)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:55)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:27)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:210)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:175)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:93)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:108)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:85)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:370)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:361)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:126)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:154)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:94)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:50)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:88)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:408)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:929)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:969)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:928)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:407)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

:app:kaptDevDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDevDebugKotlin'.

  > Compilation error. See log for more detailsВне

Comment: Где-то проблема с Dagger-ом: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity, androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder.SupportParentable>`. Попробуйте пересобрать с очисткой всех кэшей и т.п.

Comment: Уже пробовал, и инвалидейт/рестарт и физически убивал. Версию даггера поднимал с 2.10 до 2.20, котлина с 1.3.0 до 1.3.11 и обратно на 1.2.71, пробовал так же gradle 4.6 обновлять до 4.8 и 4.10.2... Без особого результата... Проблема наблюдается на 2-х разных ноутах, на винде и на маке, на разных версиях android studio

Comment: Тогда откатывайте изменения в коде, пока не заработает.

Comment: Проблемма в том, что не собирается код, который собирался ранее...

Comment: Значит зависимости или плагины обновились. Что-то изменилось.